# Bach Invention 1 BWV 772 Bar 13 same note simultaneously in both staves, play only one?

Tags: piano, key, clefs

I'm learning Bach's Invention 1 BWV 772. Bar 13 has the same note E in both staves simultaneously. Should I only use right hand to play it?

(I saw some past questions about both staves having the same note simultaneously but the answers seem to be mostly about different voices)

[image]

Comment: Hi seamurmurs. This question answers that and points out the reason is due to different voices, but also tells you how to play them in general (one answer is solely devoted to this in the duplicate)

Comment: "Different voices" is exactly the issue here. In this piece, the treble staff is considered to be one "voice", and the bass staff a second "voice."