# Same note on two staves in a piano score

Tags: piano, notation, technique, sheet-music

These are bars 56–59 in Patrik Pietschmann's arrangement of Hans Zimmer's "Interstellar Main Theme"

[image: mm. 56–57]
[image: mm. 58–59]

**How does one deal with the Es that appear in both staves?**

The first two bars I can play by holding the LH's E and releasing it to play the RH's one, and then hitting it again (so that the left hand ends up playing three sequences of an eighth note and  an eighth note rest) This sounds nice, and is the approach suggested by answers to [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/4670/88149) A well known example of this is the first Gymnopédie

For the next two bars, though, that does not really work, as far as I can tell.

Comment: While waiting for answers, here is a somewhat related one: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/120683/bach-invention-2-bar-13-overlapping-keys-for-both-hands-while-playing-mordent

Comment: How about holding down the eb an octava lower without playing the tone? Its harmonics will be heard and resound on each attack of the higher notes played by the right hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece is intended to be played with the sustain (damper) pedal. Just keep the pedal down through the entire passage. Pedal use can be heard throughout his own recording of the piece.

However, more telling is, in fact, his recording, in which he doesn't play the left hand E at all. Here is the video, timed to measure 58 (the measure numbers appear in small print at the left of the video).

Answer (score 0):

In the first bar you show, you press the sostenuto (middle) pedal then play the first note in the treble and bass clefs; both the treble and bass Es will sustain, but that should work fine. If you don't have a sostenuto pedal on your piano, you'll have to figure out a workaround.

Comment: Yes. I am asking for a workaround. That's the question.

Comment: Electronic or acoustic workaround?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - no mention of a workaround in the question! However, **IF** your piano has a middle pedal which is sostenuto, then empty's answer is slightly more applicable. If it only has a sustain pedal, go with Aaron's answer - there's no real alternative way to play it. Most pianos on the left of the Atlantic will have said sostenuto, as will most good electronic pianos. Not so with acoustics on the right.